# How to return Swagger UI HTML as string using Swashbuckle

Tags: swashbuckle

In ASP.NET Core or Classic ASP.NET we can use [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) to Generate beautiful API documentation, including a UI to explore and test operations, directly from your routes, controllers and models.

I have different user case. I already have swagger `.json` file (version 2.0). I want to load that file into Swashbuckle, and can Swashbuckle return Swagger UI HTML as string?

Once i get string, i am going to use it somewhere else in down the line process

Answer (score 0):

Swashbuckle just uses SwaggerUI which is open source. You can just use SwaggerUI directly.

[SwaggerUI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/)

You can also use something like this to visualize your Swagger.

[Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/)

Comment: I dont see SwaggerUI has any .nuget package

Comment: SwaggerUI isn't a nuget package, it's a web application that you can deploy and then use to display your Swagger. What Swashbuckle does is integrate that web application into your application so that it can display Swagger generated from your application. If you have swagger the is not generated by Swashbuckle then you really need some other way to display it, something like SwaggerUI. Swashbuckle is not meant to display swagger json that it did not generate.

Comment: If you don't want to run your own SwaggerUI site you can check this out...

https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/index

Comment: but regardless who generate swagger `.json` Swashbuckle or other service, it needs to follow swagger specification.So i was hoping Swashbuckle will be able to load it

Comment: There may be a way to get swashbuckle to load it, I don't know, but like I said, that's not really what swashbuckle is meant for. If you have existing swagger json that was not created via Swashbuckle then you really should find another way to host and display it.